# Rails many-to-one relationship aggregate functions (group, count) active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, active-record-query

I have two models in a many-to-one relationship:

```
class Event
  has_many :comments 
end

class Comment
  # notice enum for comment status: pending => 0, approved => 1
  enum status: [:pending, :approved]
  belongs_to :event
end
```

I would like to get some comment stats on a given event. For example for event with id 1, find all of its comments and calculate how many comments are pending and approved. e.g return data for event with id 1 and its comment stats

```
    [
      id: 1, #event id and all event related data 
      comment_stats = { pending: 3, approved: 20} 
   ]
```

Also the data should contain all the Event fields as well as a comment_stats hash

I am stuck as to what approach to take.

My first attempt is as follow

```
event = Event.find(params[:id])
event.messages.select(:status)
```

Here is where I need to do the grouping and count comment stats for event with id 1.

This gives me back an array of messages e.g.

```
    [
      { " id":null, "status": "pending"}, 
      { "id": null, "status": "approved"} ...
   ]
```

Here I would like to group this array of hashed as such:

```
comment_stats = { pending: 3, approved: 20}
```

I am really out of idea. I'd greatly appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Event
  def stats
    {
      event_id:      id,
      event:         self,
      comment_stats: {
        pending:  comments.where(status: Comment.statutes[:pending]).count,
        approved: comments.where(status: Comment.statutes[:approved]).count
      }
    }
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
event = Event.find(params[:id])
event.stats
#=> { event_id: 1, event: <Event object>, comment_stats: { pending:  10, approved: 20 } }
event.stats[:comment_stats]
#=> { pending:  10, approved: 20 }
```

Comment: How could one flatten out the nested hash of hashes so that there is only one hash with nested comment_stats hash e.g. 
{ event_data,  comment_stats: { pending:  10, approved: 20 } } ? 

Instead of  
{ event : { id: 1, etc }, comment_stats:{ pending:  10, approved: 20 }  }

Comment: @ElvynMejia you can add a method to the class `Event`: `def self.stats
    all.each_with_object({}) { |event, hash| hash[event] = event[:comment_stats] }
  end` - this will return single hash where key is event instance, and value is it's stats.

Comment: It won't let me edit because it's too short but shouldn't `Comment.statutes` be `Comment.status`?

Comment: @MageeWorld [no, plural is correct](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).

Comment: I don't mean to be a smart ass - but when did statutes become the plural of status?

Comment: @MageeWorld if you don't - why the question then? ;) 1) It was OP who edited. 2) Both *status*  and *statuses* are allowed/considered correct when it comes to plural of *status* AFAIK. 3) It by no means relevant to neither question nor answer.

Comment: Right but the answer says statutes - so I was trying to understand it since it's something that applies (the basis) to a project i've been working on for a long while (http://github.com/jemagee/nba) which will require a lot of counting, summing, averaging, and i've been kind of afraid to even attempt it as it's pretty involved - (not one to pick easy starter projects - wish i was)

Comment: By the way - is this faster than creating a scope in the comments model and using join to access the scopes?

Comment: @MageeWorld i assume scopes could speed it up a little, but it's not backed by any benchmark. I would use scopes definitely, because it at least cleans things up a bit

Comment: @MageeWorld here is a good article that explains queries with enums.https://hackhands.com/ruby-on-enums-queries-and-rails-4-1/

Comment: @AndreyDeineko scopes definitely clean up the code a little plus it allows chaining.